# Is there a way in python to execute a statement like 'for min(x, y) do z' without an if-else logic?

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement

Is there a shorter way of writing an if-else loop in a scenario where I have a comparison between two numbers as condition?

Here is a pseudo-code example:

```
a = 10
b = 15

c = None


if a > b:
    c = b
elif a < b:
    c = a
```

Is there a way in python to take the expression above and shorten it?

My thoughts so far have lead me to ideas like `for min(x, y) do z`, but I don't know if that is implementable in that form in python. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just do what you said: `c = min(a,b)`?

Comment: you can do, for simple if else case,`c = a if a< b else b`

Comment: `for` is used for loops, it doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: `c = (a+b + abs(a-b))//2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are two ways you could do that. Python has a built in function `min()` which, like you said, will return the minimum of two values

```
c = min(a,b)
```

Or you can put an if in one line like this

```
c = b if b<a else a
```

Hope this helps